# LINQ2SQL: orderby note.hasChildren(), name ascending

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, treeview, hierarchical-data

I have a **hierarchical data structure** which I'm displaying in a webpage **as a treeview.**

I want to data to be ordered to first show nodes ordered alphabetically which have no children, **then** under these nodes ordered alphabetically which have children. **Currently** I'm ordering all nodes in one group, which means nodes with children appear next to nodes with no children.

I'm using a recursive method to build up the treeview, which has this LINQ code at it's heart:

```
    var filteredCategory = from c in category
                           orderby c.Name ascending
                           where c.ParentCategoryId == parentCategoryId && c.Active == true
                           select c;
```

So this is the orderby statement I want to enhance.

Shown below is the database table structure:

```
[dbo].[Category](
    [CategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Level] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ParentCategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Selectable] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Category_Selectable]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Category_Active]  DEFAULT ((1))
```

Comment: I don't see any question to answer here: if this is not working, then say what results you are expecting, and what you are getting.

Comment: At the moment I'm ordering by then name ascending. I want to group the names into two group, first ones with no children - then a second with children.

Comment: Uhm... I just noticed ParentCategoryId can't be null.  
**How do you know which Categories have no parent?**  
I hope you are enforcing Foreign Key on ParentCategoryId, and not using 0 or something else to mark that it has no parent... that would be a really bad practice.

Comment: It did used to be null - but that lead to a problem, so I changed it to 0. (I can't remember was the issue was now, as it was early on in the design)

Comment: But now you can't have a Foreign Key constraint to ensure that all ParentCategoryId are valid. So it's possible that somehow you loose database consistency, and all of a sudden you have Categories that do exist but never show up, or that you can't put under a parent because the id 12345 just doesn't exist anymore. Do you see the kind of troubles I am pointing? In my opinion the trouble of having to handle null values in that field is much preferable - and it's more semantically correct.

Comment: Another example of problems that can arise from not using nulls: I have worked in a project where we integrated data between our application and another application (to and from). The other application marked "unknown" dates as 1-1-1900... for all DateTime fields, including birthdate. There **are** people that were born in 1-1-1900, so it's possible that a date that was actually known would get treated as unknown.

Comment: I agree - but like I said, the use of nulls caused a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var filteredCategory = category
  .Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == parentCategoryId
    && c.Active == true)
  .OrderBy(c => c.Children.Any() ? 1 : 2)
  .ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

If you don't have a Children property, go to the linq to sql designer and create an association that adds the property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace c.Category) with the child IQueryable<>:

```
var filteredCategory = from c in category 
       orderby c.Category.Count == 0
       where c.ParentCategoryId == parentCategoryId && c.Active == true 
       select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linq2SQL, can't you build the tree by just getting all the Categories without parent, and then access the children as needed to build the tree?

I mean something like this query to select the root Categories:

```
Category[] rootCats = (from c in category
    orderby c.Name ascending
    where c.ParentCategoryId == 0 // that is, no parent = root element
        && c.Active == true
    select c).ToArray();
```

And then accessing the children of a given Category (`IEnumerable<Category>`) via `oneCat.Category.Where( cat => cat.Active == true)`.